# How can i convert ad date to shamsi date in access datebase file

Tags: ms-access

I have simple table on access database system,this field datatype is `date/time` field and 
save into this field ad date type and i want to convert this field to shamsi date.
can i use VBA?
How Can i convert with access sql?